# How to solve an equation with one unknown variable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am not sure what the concept is called but let me explain. I apologize if this is something trivial, but I am not sure what this method is called or which library to use. My goal is to solve for one variable of a formula if I have the other two. For example: I want to define an equation as:

> A + B = C

**Pseudo code**

```
def solve_equation(a, b, or c): # I know this does not make sense form a syntax perspective 
    formula = ( c = a + b)
    solve(formula, x) # x would be the the desirable variable e.g. inputs a,c, then x = b
    return x
```

**Solve for A**

> A = C - B

```
solve_equation(b = 2, c = 3)
```

Output = 1

**Solve for B**

> B = C - A

```
solve_equation(a = 1, c = 3)
```

Output = 2

**Solve for C**

> C = A + B

```
solve_equation(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Output = 3

Hopefully, this explains a little better of what my goal is. I have used solve() before, and I have symbolically rearranged formulas to my need. What I am confused is how to do both at the same time. I work with complex formulas with many more variables, so manually coding the formula to solve every variable becomes complicated. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem for general cases (since you mentioned that you _"work with complex formulas with many more variables"_). You might have a look at third party libraries such as SymPy.

Comment: I mainly use sympy, I am not sure how to implement the problem above. I have used their solve feature.

Comment: You can also do something like this. `a=1;b=2; c = eval("a+b")` as a quick dirty trick.

Comment: @iamvegan What if they want to solve for `a` instead?

Comment: @LuisEnriquez-Contreras `I am not sure how to implement the problem above. I have used their solve feature.`: In that case, it is better to post the code you wrote that did not work and ask for help about that.